# Creation operator on coherent state and issue with commutation relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bosons, coherent-states

If our bosonic annihilation and creation operators are $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$, then for any complex number $\varphi$ we can define the (unnormalized) coherent state
$$ | \varphi \rangle \equiv e^{\varphi a^\dagger}|0\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |n\rangle. $$

Part of the beauty is that when acting on such coherent states, we can replace $a \to \varphi$ and $a^\dagger \to \partial_\varphi$. For example, to prove this:
$$\boxed{ a^\dagger |\varphi\rangle } = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\varphi^{n} \sqrt{n+1} }{\sqrt{n!}} |n+1\rangle =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\varphi^{(n+1)-1} (n+1)}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}} |n+1\rangle = \boxed{\partial_\varphi |\varphi\rangle}.$$

> My question is now the following: **how is this consistent with the
>   canonical commutation relations?** The issue:
>   $$ \boxed{ [a,a^\dagger] |\varphi\rangle } =  (aa^\dagger-a^\dagger a) |\varphi\rangle =(\varphi \partial_\varphi - \underbrace{\partial_\varphi \varphi}_{= 1 + \varphi \partial_\varphi}) |\varphi\rangle= \boxed{ - |\varphi\rangle }. $$
>   I.e., this would imply that $[a,a^\dagger] =-1$ instead of
>   $[a,a^\dagger] =1$. Where have I gone astray?

Curiously, Altland and Simons claim all is good in their book, but they magically insert a minus sign halfway, which seems like a typo if it weren't for the fact that it gives the desired result! Here is a screenshot of p159 of the second edition:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\vert #1 \rangle} $
The issue is that $a^\dagger\ket{\phi} = \partial_\phi\ket\phi$ no longer is a coherent state. Hence $ aa^{\dagger}\ket\phi \neq \phi\partial_\phi\ket\phi $ but rather
$$ aa^{\dagger}\ket\phi = \partial_\phi \phi\ket\phi $$ which looks totally counter-intuitive, but can be easily verified using the Taylor expansion. It also coincides with the first term given in the formula from Altland.

I'll let you work out $a^\dagger a$.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thanks! Also fun that the number operator then corresponds to the dilatation operator, i.e., $\hat n = a^\dagger a = \varphi \partial_\varphi$. (I still feel that the excerpt from Altland and Simons---although factually correct---is very misleading.)